# Other ways of counting number of keywords in a complex string

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am reading a file which contains approx 1200 words in the following format:

> words:a:/zenb:/fixx:/wew:/sina:/benb:/sixx:/hew:/bin

I need to find how many keywords are there in that text file, by keyword i mean:

> zen fix we sin ben six he bin

Right now I am trying to do it with RegExp like this:

```
var s:String = "words:b:sa:/zenb:/fixx:/wew:/sina:/benb:/sixx:/hew:/bin";
var pattern:RegExp = /:/+/g;
var results:Array = s.match(pattern);
trace(results.length);
```

Its producing an error, since I am a beginner I really don't understand how this RegExp work , are there any alternate methods to get the same results?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `var pattern:RegExp = /:/+/g;` has a syntax error, you skipped a backslash `\` change this to :

```
var pattern:RegExp = /:\/+/g;
```

and it should work, Alternatively with this format you can use the String split method to get the total word count. Try this:

```
var s:String = "words:b:sa:/zenb:/fixx:/wew:/sina:/benb:/sixx:/hew:/bin";
var wordCount:Number = s.split(":/").length -1;
trace( wordCount );
```

Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class CountWordsExample extends Sprite
    {
        public function CountWordsExample()
        {
            super();
            // 8 7 0
            trace(countWords(
                "words:b:sa:/zenb:/fixx:/wew:/sina:/benb:/sixx:/hew:/bin",
                ":/"),
                countWords(
                    "words:b:sa:/:/fixx:/wew:/sina:/benb:/sixx:/hew:/bin",
                    ":/"),
                countWords(
                    "words:b:sa::zenb::fixx::wew::sina::benb::sixx::hew::bin",
                    ":/"));
        }

        public static function countWords(words:String, delimiter:String, 
                                          countBlanks:Boolean = false):uint
        {
            var result:uint;
            var wordPointer:int = -1;
            var delimiterPointer:int;
            var delimiterLength:uint = delimiter.length;

            if (words.length >= delimiterLength)
            {
                do
                {
                    delimiterPointer = wordPointer;
                    wordPointer = words.indexOf(
                        delimiter, wordPointer + delimiterLength);
                    if (countBlanks || 
                        // we moved by more characters, then the length of
                        // delimiter
                        wordPointer - delimiterLength > delimiterPointer) 
                        result++;
                }
                while (wordPointer > -1)
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how to count words without ever creating additional arrays or sub-strings of the original string. It also verifies that the words counted have at least one character length.